# Problem while time needed in a multi select date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-7

We're in a need to select multiple dates with a time. Not a range, need to select random dates. But multiDatesPicker only selecting multiple dates alone without time.

Checked some of the gems like datepicker and dateTimePicker, but no use. Any gem or blog suggestion to achieve selecting multiple dates with time?

[date_picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUgCO.png)

Comment: question should properly formatted include only required tags , output image, your error code, what exact error

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI I've added a screen shot for date picker to select single date. Now I needed a date picker to select multiple dates with time as in a shared screen shot

Comment: multiple date select means ? can you add code also

Answer (score 0):

your tags are wrong , if you need in jquery then below will help you.

but below needs small bootstrap-datepicker.js file, try it .

```js
   $('.date').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```

```html
 

 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <h3> Multi Select Date Picker</h3>
        <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
    </div>
```

comment if any query